# Do we need backpropagation if there is only one class?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

A am interested in physiologic neural network. Altough there are some opposite views, most probably there seems to be no plausible way to explain a physiologic backpropagation in the brain.

So I am trying to code a neural network without backpropagation yet my mathematical  understanding is inadaquate, so I want to ask folowing simple question:

“If we do have only one node at the right side of the network, accepting that the inputs are on the left, can we train the network without backpropoagation and using the mean of weights instead? As we would know the y for all x it should be possible to calculate the mean w?”

The idea is that the system should work continiously, and train continiously for one class, until the trained network decides that the input is different from the known previously trained classes. And if it is different, it should create and train for that new class of inputs. I think that should be the working system of the brain, and as the cortex has similar cells, mathematically it also must be that easy?

But where is my flaw (with simplified math please :))

Comment: If there is only one class, why do you need a neural network at all? Just do `function getClass(input) {return "class 0";}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. True. But would a training result in a mean of weights? If yes, then it would be able to differentiate that class 0 from others, that are significantly different from “other” classes.Than it would begin to train for that new “ class”…So we would reach a new class producing system or general intelligence without backpropagation?

Comment: If there's only one class there is nothing to differentiate. If you have "class" vs "not class" that's 2 classes

Comment: I am really sorry for my childish question, but I do want to understand: If we know the range of  x that would be a cluster of information, and classify that information as class 0, wouldnt that be still one class to train?

Comment: *I* don't understand what the purpose of a network with only one class is. You ask it what class a cat is, and it says class 0... you ask it what class a dog is, and it says class 0... you ask it what the sky is, and it says class 0... because that's the only possible thing it can output... so why bother having a neural network at all?

Comment: Lets say there is a network we trained for a class(class0) of information(input (x,y) , say, that is a cluster of dots in a range of  2<x<4 and 3<y<5, we would be able to say that a point (2.5,4.5) is in this class ( class 0) and not in another class. Lets think that the information ,coming continiously,is  seperable, that is lets say there is another class( class 1) which as at least 10 units distant from the class 0, as an example,a cluster of dots in the range of 12<x<14 and  13<y<15, for that the network should begin for another class to train.

Comment: Oh so you are not just looking for a one-class neural network, but for one that can learn more and more classes, starting with one. Do you at least know that some data *isn't* in the class?

Comment: Yes, exactly, a one by one learning neural network.No, I was thinking, that can be calculated from naive statistics, whether it is “significantly” according to the weights to the same class or not..

Comment: The point is, that we need backpropagation if more than 1 classes, but there should be no need for bp, if there is only one class, which can be trained in realtime…That would be more near to physiologic brain. As you did understand what I was meaning, could you please give some examples near that idea?

Comment: *If there is only one class then your neural network is completely useless and doesn't do anything*

Comment: @Eren no meaning if you classify to 1 class, but a little ok if you regress to zero value

Comment: I was trying to ask One Class SVM… It solved my question